# Alterar legenda de horas no Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou gerando um gráfico de vendas por horas no Power BI, e me deparei com um problema.
Necessito alterar a legenda do gráfico, por exemplo, "de 08:00 para 08 - 09", isso para ficar mais claro de que cada coluna no gráfico se refere aquele período específico.

Primeiro agrupei as horas (de hora em hora), isso pois são muitos registros de vendas.

Porém, tentei de três formas via DAX mudar esta informação da legenda, e o Power BI sempre acusa que não tem como, com o seguinte erro: *A função 'SWITCH' não oferece suporte à comparação de valores do tipo Date com valores do tipo Text. Considere usar a função VALUE ou FORMAT para converter um dos valores.*

Abaixo o gráfico atual.
[Gráfico de vendas em horas por filial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzsa.png)

E as três tentativas via DAX

Tentativa via switch

```
AbvHora = SWITCH('public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)], "08:00", "08 - 09")
```

Tentativa com var

```
AbvHora2 = 

    VAR hora = 'public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)]

    VAR hora2 = 'public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)] + 1

    RETURN hora & "-" & hora2
```

Tentativa com if

```
AbvHora3 = IF('public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)] = "08:00", FORMAT("08 - 09", "outros"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o problema, você pode usar a função FORMAT para formatar o texto da legenda do gráfico. A função FORMAT permite que você formate um valor em um formato específico.

Para formatar a legenda do gráfico, basta criar uma medida que utilize a função FORMAT para formatar a hora inicial e a hora final da legenda. A medida ficaria assim:

```
Legenda Hora =
    FORMAT('public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)], "hh:mm") & " - " &
    FORMAT(DATEADD('public pdv'[pdvhora (compartimentos)], 1, HOUR), "hh:mm")
```

Essa medida vai concatenar a hora inicial com a hora final, separadas por um traço (-). A hora final é obtida adicionando 1 hora à hora inicial com a função DATEADD.

Depois de criar essa medida, basta alterar a legenda do gráfico para usar essa medida ao invés da hora original.